# RegEx sample help for Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-negation

I am looking to build a regex for JavaScript.

- Condition 1 Range a-z,A-Z,0-9 are mandatory,
- Condition 2 can have any of these special chars. `~!@#$&*(),;:'-_`

Other chars should fail.

### Edit

I did try `/[a-zA-Z0-9][\~\!\@\#\$*0\-_]/` It got failed for `^`

Comment: you haven't provided 
1. enough information to understand your requirement for the regex
2. a valid code sample showing what you tried
3. valid test cases -- Do all that and maybe then you'll get help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a regexp that matches all the allowed characters, along with a lookahead that matches at least one of the required characters. The regexp needs to be anchored to match the entire input.

```
(?=.*[a-zA-Z0-9])^[a-zA-Z0-9~!@#$&*(),;:'\-_]*$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/Xmempw/1)